# What does the operator delete[] do?

Tags: c++, memory

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
  public:
    int s;
    // ~A(){}
};

int main(){
  A *c = new A[10];  

  delete c;
  return 0;
}
```

Code above can run successfully, but when i  code will get an error. Who can tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

You **must** write `delete[] c;` if `c` is a pointer to memory allocated with `new[]`.

(Interestingly, some compilers sort out this mess for your, but don't rely on that since then you're not writing portable C++).

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean. But why I got an error when I add a destructor for class A? I am confused.

Comment: That's the nature of undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: OK. By the way, if I `A *a = new A[10] ` to get an array. Will g++ place the length of a in `(int*)a - 1` ? Just like other compilers do.

Comment: I think it might put the length at `(size_t*)a - 1`, but I'm not sure.